# For which $\alpha$ does this function have a positive solution?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

> For which $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ does $$e^{\alpha x}-1=x$$ have a positive solution
>   **Hint**; Consider Derivatives at $0$.

My attempt;
Now firstly I will rewrite this to form the function $$f(x)=e^{\alpha x}-1-x$$ Now we want to see for what $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ does $f(x)=0$ yield a positive solution.
Taking derivatives we get $$f'(x)=\alpha e^{\alpha x}-1$$ and a $x=0$ we get $$f'(0)=\alpha -1$$.
Now I seem confused on how to proceed, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yup, you are almost there. Look at the curve $e^{\alpha x} -1$ and the line y =x. If this line is tangent to the curve at x = 0, this is the only solution. If not, everywhere else, the line will touch two points as @Santosh Linkha has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

$x=0$ is trivial solution. $y = x $ is a straight line passing passing through origin having slope $1$.If $\alpha < 0$ the graph is flipped about the $y$-axis and $e^{ax}-1$ will intersect $x$ at most one point so $\alpha >0$.

Since $y = e^{ax}-1$ is a nice curve, it will intersect $y=x$ at most two points. this means you need to find the value of $\alpha$ for which $y=x$ will be tangent to $y = e^{ax}-1$ at the origin.

That you will find $\alpha = 1$. Beyond this value, $e^{\alpha x}-1$ will increase exponentially and only touch at one point. So you need $0 < \alpha < 1$.

Comment: I'm not sure of the etiquette here - aren't we supposed to post something as an answer only if it is complete? Sorry - not trying to be combative.

Comment: @Sun sure ... i'll add the answer if you want.